# GData and iOS Fetching all events from all calendars?

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I have a google calendar with 5 calendars in it.
I know how to fetch each calendar to get its events, but i am looking for a way to fetch all the calendars at once?

Any help will be appreciated?

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before v3, the API does not allow you to fetch more than one calendar with a single request and it doesn't allow you to manipulate more than one calendar in a single request.

If this is really important to you (you're trying to reduce requests so I guess it's about performance), you could possible use the Google [App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) to create a function that would perform this work for you. I'm not sure you would see a big jump in performance though.

Now that v3 is out, you can get some information from several calendar on a single request.
Here's an example:
https://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#freebusy